# Why is it that $\omega + \omega_1 = \omega_1$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I have seen some other questions about the proofs around ordinals and $\omega$ and $\omega_1$, but some of the answers have confused me.

An ordinal $\alpha$ is countable if $\alpha < \omega_1$.

$\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal and it is assumed that for $\alpha, \beta < \omega_1$, $\alpha + \beta < \omega_1$.

Now, my initial thought, similar to the answers in the 'Prove $\omega + \omega_1 = \omega_1$' style of questions is that we substitute $\omega$ and $\omega_1$ as $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. Then I would obtain $\omega + \omega_1 < \omega_1$.

Similarly, I could substitute again into $\alpha + \beta \geq max \{\alpha, \beta \}$ to get $\omega + \omega_1 \geq max \{\omega, \omega_1 \} = \omega_1$. So we have an upper and lower bound and can claim $\omega + \omega_1 = \omega_1$.

But my question is, how does this work since $\omega_1$ is uncountable (and so we cannot say $\omega_1 < \omega_1$)?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Use the definition of ordinal addition, and the fact that adding two countable ordinals is countable.

Comment: $\alpha + \beta = sup \{\alpha + \gamma | \gamma < \beta \}$. $\omega + \omega_1 = sup \{\omega + \gamma | \gamma < \omega_1 \}$. And since $\gamma < \omega_1$ it is countable, and the supremum is the same as $\bigcup \{\omega + \gamma | \gamma < \omega_1 \}$, which is a union of countable ordinals. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. And what can be the supremum of uncountably many different countable ordinals?

Comment: would this be $\omega_1$?

Comment: What could it be?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: You asked me a question, and I answered with another question. What ordinals can be obtained by taking a supremum over an uncountable set of countable ordinals?

Comment: would they be uncountable ordinals?

Comment: Don't guess. Look at the definitions. What could be the supremum of a set of countable ordinals?

Comment: I thought generally, this could be a limit ordinal of some sort. So in my case in my first comment, it could be $\gamma$.

Comment: What's $\gamma$?

Comment: A countable ordinal. I think I might be missing what you're getting at so apologies for how slow I'm being at this

Comment: $\gamma$ is just a letter used to denote *an ordinal*. It's not a particular ordinal (like $\omega,\varepsilon_0,\omega_1$ and so on). Let's go over this again. How many countable ordinals are there? If we have a set of countable ordinals, what can its cardinality be (hint: there are three options)?

Comment: $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal and so it is the supremum of the set of countable ordinals. Can we say there are $\omega_1$ countable ordinals? Or $\aleph_1$ since $\omega_1 = \aleph_1$ in terms of cardinality. If we have a set of countable ordinals, its cardinality can be $\aleph_0$, $\aleph_1$ or another $\aleph_[]$?

Comment: If every set of countable ordinals is a subset of $\omega_1$, what sort of cardinalities can sets of countable ordinals have?

Comment: I'm really not sure

Comment: Going back to your first response that started this, "Yes. And what can be the supremum of uncountably many different countable ordinals? – Asaf Karagila" am I wrong in supposing that this cannot be anything other than $\omega_1$? Because if we have some $\delta > \omega_1$ then this $\delta$ cannot be a supremum of a set of countable ordinals as $\omega_1$ is uncountable.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly the point that I was driving at. So, since for every $\gamma<\omega_1$ we know that $\omega+\gamma$ is countable; what is $\sup\{\omega+\gamma\mid\gamma<\omega_1\}$?

Comment: $sup\{\omega+\gamma | \gamma < \omega_1\}$ is $\bigcup\{\omega+\gamma | \gamma <\omega_1\}$

Comment: Yes, but the supremum, or union, of a set of ordinals is an ordinal. What ordinal is this?

Comment: I thought it was $\omega_1$, but now I'm thinking it can't be because otherwise it would not be countable.

Comment: Why does it have to be countable? $\alpha+\beta$ is countable if (and only if) **both** ordinals are countable. $\omega_1$ is uncountable, so it doesn't apply.

Comment: Oh yes. Will you tell me what $sup \{\omega + \gamma | \gamma < \omega_1 \}$ is please? Because I thought the way of proving $\omega + \omega_1 = \omega_1$ was to find an upper and lower bound. I thought the upper bound was somehow found by showing $\omega + \omega_1 < \omega_1$ (which made no sense to be but that is why I asked the question of how this works in the first place) and then a lower bound was given by showing $\omega + \omega_1 \geq max \{\omega, \omega_1 \} = \omega_1$. Then putting this together gave $\omega + \omega_1 = \omega_1$.

Comment: But again, I may be completely off track. And so if $sup \{\omega + \gamma | \gamma < \omega_1 \}$ is $\omega_1$, then we would not need this two cases thing.

Comment: I am not going to reveal the answer anymore than I have. If I give it to you, you will never have it. If you find it on your own, no one will ever be able to take it away from you.

Comment: Stop over complicating things. Stick to the definitions, and use everything that we have discussed. You don't need an upper and lower bounds. You can calculate this *directly*.

Comment: I've been staring at the same definitions and our discussion, and I can't see how $sup \{\omega + \gamma | \gamma < \omega_1 \}$ can be anything other than $\omega_1$. So $sup \{\omega + \gamma | \gamma < \omega_1 \}$ = $\omega_1$.

Comment: Yes, it is $\omega_1$.

Comment: So to summarise, $\omega + \omega_1 = sup \{\omega + \gamma | \gamma < \omega_1 \}$. This is an uncountable union (since $\omega_1$ is uncountable) of countably many ordinals (since for $\gamma < \omega_1$, $\omega + \gamma$ is countable. This $sup = \omega_1$. It cannot be some $\delta > \omega_1$ because then $\delta$ could not be a supremum of a set of countable ordinals as $\omega_1$ is uncountable. This is rather wordy, but is this correct?

Comment: Except for the typo "countably many ordinals" instead of "countable ordinals", it looks fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13655/discussion-between-math-student-91-and-asaf-karagila)

Comment: I'm sorry. I have a great dislike to the chat system here. I am also intermittently online at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You should really think of $\alpha+\beta$ as the result of "concatenating" an order of type $\alpha$ with one of type $\beta$. Formally, this is the ordinal corresponding to the well-order on $(\alpha\times\{0\})\cup(\beta\times\{1\})$, ordered by $(a,i)<(b,j)$ iff $i=j$ and $a<b$, or else $i<j$. Think of this as putting $\alpha$ dots in a row, and then $\beta$ additional dots.

To show $\omega+\omega_1=\omega_1$, it is enough to see that, in fact, already $\omega+\omega^2=\omega^2$ (and therefore $\omega+\beta=\beta$ for any $\beta\ge\omega^2$). For this, note that $1+\omega=\omega$, which should be clear from the "dots description": You have $\omega$ dots in a row, if you add an extra dot at the beginning, that is still just $\omega$ dots in a row. Now, $\omega^2$ is simply the result of replacing each of these dots with $\omega$ many.

Answer (score 0):

"Pictorially", the result is clear. If you draw a line, mark the points of $\omega$ on this line from left to right and then mark the points of $\omega_1$, it is more or less obvious that the resulting (well) ordered set is isomorphic to $\omega_1$.

One may explain this as follows.

The countable ordinals start like this: $0, 1, 3,\dots ,\omega, \omega+1, \omega+2, \omega+3,\dots ,\omega+\omega=\omega\cdot 2, \omega\cdot 2+1, \omega\cdot 2+2,\omega\cdot 2+3,\dots ,\omega\cdot 2+\omega=\omega\cdot 3,\dots ,\omega\cdot n,\dots , \omega\cdot\omega, \dots $

If you add $\omega=\{ 0,1,2, 3,\dots \}$ on the left; this gives you the "sequence" $0,1,2,\dots , 0,1,2,\dots ,\omega, \omega+1,\omega+2,\dots ,\omega\cdot 2, \dots $.

Now relabel your sequence in the obvious way: the second "$0$" is relabelled "$\omega$", the second "$1$" is relabelled "$\omega+1$", ..., "$\omega$" is relabelled "$\omega\cdot 2$", ..., "$\omega\cdot 2$" is relabelled "$\omega\cdot 3$" and so on.

The transfinite sequence thus obtained is exactly $\omega_1$, i.e. $\omega+\omega_1=\omega_1$.

A more "formal" proof would consist in doing what Asaf suggests.

Answer (score -2):

Every ordinal number can be expressed as a multiple of $\omega^2$ plus an ordinal number less than $\omega^2$. If you take any multiple of $\omega^2$ and left add $\omega$, you get back the exact same ordinal number. If you take any countable multiple of $\omega^2$ and right add any ordinal number less than $\omega^2$, you still get a countable ordinal. Thus, $\omega_1$ is a multiple of $\omega^2$ and so $\omega + \omega_1 = \omega_1$.